# Python json print key from structure

Tags: python, json

I have this structure

```
> api.open_orders(url.api)
[                               # List of open orders
    {
        'id': string,           ## Order ID
        'type': string,         ## Order type - one of
    }, ...
]
```

I tried to print with print int(open_o['type']) but does not want to work

> TheTraceback (most recent call last):   File "tr1.py", line 11, in
>     print int(open_o['type']) TypeError: list indices must be
>   integers, not str

Does anyone have any idea how to print 'type'?

Comment: Try `[0]["type"]` instead of `["type"]` in your sample to get at the type value in the dict stored at the first slot (indexed with 0) of the list. Cf. my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
api.open_orders(url.api)[0]["type"]
```

The traceback tells you, that you have a list, where you index into with type, so the first dict is one level more deeply nested as element at index 0 of the list (the square brackets denote a list and also the index operator which is OK as we do not have so many characters in ASCII to work as language tokens, but sometimes irritates).

Comment: Nice, works! I have this **api.sell_limit_order(url.api) { 'price': decimal, 'amount': decimal}** How can I set those two arguments?